# \maketitle redefinition and several authors

Tags: titles

for the moment I've redefined `\maketitle` as

```
\makeatletter
 \def\maketitle{%
 \begin{center}
  \vspace*{3mm}%
  \textbf{\large{\MakeUppercase{\@title}}}%
  \par\vspace*{5mm}{\@author}%
  \par\vspace*{10mm}%
 \end{center}%
 }
\makeatother
```

that's look as I want. Of course in the field `\author` I can add also addres and email, i.e:

```
\author{\uppercase{F. Irst} \\%
  \textit{bla bla bal} \\% 
  \textsc{Email}: \texttt{f.irst@something.edu}\\[2mm]
  \uppercase{S. Econd} \\%
  \textit{etc etc etc} \\%
  \textsc{Email}: \texttt{s.econd@somethingelse.edu}%
  }
```

What I would like is to make this automatic, i.e. I would like to write something as

```
\author{F. Irst}
\address{bla bla bal}
\email{f.irst@something.edu}
\author{S. Econd}
\address{etc etc etc}
\email{s.econd@somethingelse.edu}
```

and get what I have written above. In order to do so I have to

1. define some new fields `\address` and `\email`
2. make possible that every time I write these commands (`\author`, `\address` and `\email`) their value are not just overwritten but they sould be able to add something to the paper.

Is it possible to do something like that? How can I do?

Comment: You don't HAVE to use \maketitle.  It is supposed to make titles easier, not harder.

Comment: Since the format of titles are typically bound to the document class, could you provide us with a minimal example that replicates your current behaviour? That way we know where the foundation blocks are from where one can build...

Comment: The behavior I want to replicate is the one written in my post as a second code sample